# ubuntu 16.04 shutdown problem in hp laptop celeron

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

i have installed ubuntu 16.04 lts on my laptop but i can't shutdown my laptop
just if i hold on power button i tried `shutdown -h now` & `sudo init 0` but same thing and when i type in the terminal `systemctl status poweroff.target`
it's shows

```
 ● poweroff.target - Power-Off
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
lines 1-4/4 (END)
```

Comment: i'v solved this by changing usb3.0 to usb2.0 in bios